# Set Windows Process 'Comment' via .Net?

Tags: .net, windows, process, comments

When looking at my Windows tasks via Microsoft's/Sysinternal's Process Explorer I can see/modify a process's 'Comment' attribute. Is it possible to set this attribute programmatically from within the process itself somehow in a .Net application or this something specific to Process Explorer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This feature is specific to Process Explorer; basically it allows you to tag a process with something so you can keep track of what is going on.  From the Process Explorer help file:

> Enter a comment for a process in the Comment field. Comments are visible in the process view in the Comment column, or if you do not have the comment column selected, in the tool tip that displays when you hover the mouse over a process. Comments apply to all processes with the same path and are remembered from execution to execution.